# Is it possible to get the user role inside middleware using Next-Auth5? (Aauth JS) and next 14?

Tags: authentication, next-auth, next.js14

I've been having problems getting full user model inside the middleware.. when I get the user it only displays their name email and picture.

I have the session callback and I can control user roles on the server rendered pages but I really would like to add that extra layer of protection and do it through middleware insetead!

**This is my auth.config.ts file:**
`

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import Github from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import { LoginSchema } from './schemas'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { getUserByEmail } from './server/database/user'

export default {
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    Github({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET
    }),
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validateFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials)

        if (validateFields.success) {
          const { email, password } = validateFields.data

          const user = await getUserByEmail(email)
          if (!user || !user.password) return null

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

          if (passwordsMatch) return { ...user, password: '', role: user.role }
        }
        return null
      }
    })
  ]
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

**This is my auth .ts file**

```
import NextAuth, { Session } from 'next-auth'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'
import authConfig from '@/auth.config'
import { db } from '@/lib/db'
import { getUserById } from '@/server/database/user'
import { getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId } from './server/database/two-factor-confirmation'

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut
} = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: '/sign-in',
    error: '/auth-error'
  },
  events: {
    async linkAccount({ user }) {
      await db.user.update({
        where: { id: user.id },
        data: { emailVerified: new Date() }
      })
    }
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account }) {
      //allows users with Oauth providers to access the page
      if (account?.provider !== 'credentials') return true

      const existingUser = await getUserById(user.id ?? '')

      //prevents signing in non existing users
      if (!existingUser) {
        return false
      }
      //prevents signing in without email verification
      if (!existingUser.emailVerified) return false

      //* Added two factor authentication

      if (existingUser.isTwoFactorEnabled) {
        const twoFactorConfirmation = await getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId(
          existingUser.id
        )

        if (!twoFactorConfirmation) return false

        //Delete two factor confirmation for next sign-in
        await db.twoFactorConfirmation.delete({
          where: { id: twoFactorConfirmation.id }
        })
      }

      //Todo: in middleware and in here add Admin dashboard, protected from

      return true
    },

    async jwt({ token }) {
      if (!token.sub) return token

      const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub)

      if (!existingUser) return token

      if (existingUser) {
        token.role = existingUser.role
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ token, session }: { session: Session; token?: any }) {
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub
      }

      if (token.role && session.user) {
        session.user.role = token.role
      }
      return session
    }
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
  ...authConfig
})
```

**My middleware**

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import authConfig from './auth.config'

const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig)

import {
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  apiAuthPrefix,
  authRoutes,
  publicRoutes
} from './routes'

export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl, auth } = req
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth
  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix)
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname)
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname)

  console.log(auth?.user)

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null
  }

  if (isAuthRoute) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl))
    }
    return null
  }
  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/sign-in', nextUrl))
  }

  return null
})

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)']
}
```